# GTM Click ID Trigger to the whole object

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager

I have this code:

```
<div id="hk-mobile-sticky">
    <a href="/kontakt" class="button sticky-mbutton sticky-kontakt-mobile">
            <div class=sticky-icons-mobile>
                    <span class="icn-hk-kontakt-m"></span>
            </div>
            <p class="hk-msticky-label">
                    Kontakt
            </p>
    </a>

    <a href="/standorte" class="button sticky-mbutton sticky-standorte-mobile">
            <div class=sticky-icons-mobile>
                    <span class="icn-hk-pin-m"></span>
            </div>
            <p class="hk-msticky-label">
                    Standorte
            </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now I want to have a click trigger in GTM for both `<a>` Elements – Kontakt & Standorte. My guess would be to take the class e.g. "sticky-kontakt-mobile" for the trigger but it only fires when I click on the outside of the `<span>` & `<p>` tag. I also tried wrapping both `<a>` in a `<div>` with a unique class but the outcome is the same.

How do I make the trigger firing when clicking on everything boxed inside a tag?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use Trigger "Just Link"

and the following rule

```
Click Element, Match CSS Selector, div#hk-mobile-sticky a
```

The Just Link type trigger will listen to the a tag only.

Comment: thx :) I didn't know the "Just Link" Trigger act so different from the "All Elements"

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the click handler in js works different than the one in GTM.
I assigned an id "myID" to every `<a>` tag and push the event "eventName" to the dataLayer. With this setup the event will fire no matter if I click on the `<a>` or `<span>` etc.

```
document.getElementById("myID").addEventListener("click", clickonID);

function clickonID() {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
  event: "eventName",
 });
};
```